# Update the app, overwriting the new database pre-populated in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an application that starts with a database pre-populated. I want to update the application, inserting new tables and copying the new database pre-populated.
When updating the application, if I put the version of the database to 2, it creates new tables, but does not copy the new database. But if I keep to version 1, the application stops with an error.

The database is in the assets folder and use this code to copy in the first time:

```
public class DataBaseHelper<E> extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.teste/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "teste.db";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    Context context;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            try {
                    createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {
            } else {
                    this.getReadableDatabase();
                    try {
                            copyDataBase();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new Error("Error copying database");
                    }
            }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                    checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource src) {
            try {
                    TableUtils.createTable(src, Table1.class);
                    TableUtils.createTable(src, Table2.class);
                    TableUtils.createTable(src, Table3.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource src,
                    int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                    TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table1.class, true);
                    TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table2.class, true);
                    TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table3.class, true);

                    onCreate(db, src);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
            if (myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
    }
}
```

Now, I have one more table to insert, and I'm using this code:

```
public class DataBaseHelper<E> extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.teste/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "teste.db";
private static int DB_VERSION = 2;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
Context context;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        try {
                createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                        copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
        }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource src) {
        try {
                TableUtils.createTable(src, Table1.class);
                TableUtils.createTable(src, Table2.class);
                TableUtils.createTable(src, Table3.class);
                TableUtils.createTable(src, Table4.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource src,
                int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
                TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table1.class, true);
                TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table2.class, true);
                TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table3.class, true);
                TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table4.class, true);
                onCreate(db, src);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
}
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I call copyDatabase in onUpgrade and the DB is not  copied. See:

```
TableUtils.createTable(src, Linhas.class);
TableUtils.createTable(src, Horarios.class);
TableUtils.createTable(src, Itinerarios.class);
TableUtils.createTable(src, Utils.class);
copyDataBase();
```

Any help?

**EDIT 3:**

I noticed that when we change the version of the database upgrade using the method and copied the database from asset folder, the data do not appear because the version of the database that this folder assets be less than the current version. Is there a way to copy when the new database pre-populated, change the version of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table1.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table2.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table3.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(src, Table4.class, true);
            onCreate(db, src);
```

In your onCreate you should be populating the database again with however you did it in the previous version of the app.

From what I can see you aren't making a call to copyDatabase method.

Comment: I'm not sure what "nothing" means, but perhaps you should be pre populating the database using sql instead of trying to ship a binary.

Either way, your current code is not actually populating the database once created. You now need to fix your copyDatabase method.

Comment: I was thinking here and I'll try something different tomorrow, can you give me your email if I have any questions?

I'm trying to do this for two weeks, if you can help me, thanks

Comment: Just come back to this question or ask another question. If the answer has helped, I'd appreciate if you marked it as such.

Comment: See my EDIT 2 in post

Comment: I would suggest not using a pre-populated db in as a binary file. It defeats the purpose of doing all the create table stuff.

Comment: When I change the version of the database, what happens to old data? Is it erased?

Comment: You're dropping the tables, so the data is deleted.

Comment: If you found this answer useful it would be appreciated if you gave credit. Otherwise, is there something about it that could be more correct?

Comment: It was not what I wanted, but it helped. Tks

Answer (score 0):

I could not do what I wanted. Done otherwise, using a file that populates the database in initial system startup.

```
public void execSqlFromAssets(String path, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    InputStream input;
    String text;
    try {
        input = context.getAssets().open(path + ".sql");
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
        String[] inserts = text.split(";");
        for (String insert : inserts) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(insert);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "Cant execute sql"
                        + insert : e.getMessage();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource src) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(src, Linhas.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(src, Horarios.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(src, Itinerarios.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(src, Utils.class);
        execSqlFromAssets("dump_all", db);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```